# Create a class from a XML file and use the XML content in my application (C#)?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd.exe

I have a rather complex XML file which I created a class for using the xsd tool. Now I added this created class to my project and want to access the actual XML data which is in the file. What do I do next?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Next learn about xml serialization/deserialization. [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) is tutorial ;)

Comment: @grady . You have classes generated with xsd tool. Now when you deserialize your xml, all data from xml file will be in you class instance. Then you can modify data how you want and if you want to save your data just serialize to xml file.